# Is vi command-line editing broken in sbt?

Tags: sbt

My .inputrc file configures editing-mode as 'vi'.  In recent sbt versions (since 13.10), my interactive command line defaults to vi's command-mode instead of insert-mode, so each time I hit return I have to enter 'i' or 'a' before I can type a command.  Versions prior to 13.10 do the more typical thing of defaulting to insert-mode, like bash does.

Is this a bug?  Is there a workaround?

Comment: I think this is a bug

Comment: Just tried to set `set editing-mode vi` in `.inputrc` and run SBT 0.13.12 – I see no issues with command line in there.

Comment: Thanks for checking that, Alexander.  It led me to find the fix, removing line 'set keymap vi' from my .inputrc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FIXED -- I had another line 'set keymap vi' in my .inputrc that was causing the problem.  I'm not sure why or when I put that in there, but I removed it and things are back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

`sbt` uses jline under the hood and is thus affected by your `~/.inputrc` configuration. jline is modeled on GNU read line and, as such, having `set keymap vi` *should* instruct jline to [begin in command mode](https://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html#SEC9). (That it didn't is a bug, more on that soon.) If you want to keep the keymap declaration, and you want the insert behavior, use `set keymap vi-insert`.

As to the bugginess, sbt [0.13.9](https://github.com/JetBrains/sbt-structure/blob/master/extractor/src/test/data/0.13/bare/structure-0.13.9.xml) uses [jline 2.11](https://github.com/jline/jline2/releases/tag/jline-2.11) while sbt [0.13.10](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/pull/2173) uses [jline 2.13](https://github.com/jline/jline2/releases/tag/jline-2.13). There were [136 commits](https://github.com/jline/jline2/compare/jline-2.11...jline-2.13) in that range, in which we find [this change](https://github.com/jline/jline2/compare/jline-2.11...jline-2.13#diff-d2e8d94fdb991d32dc2fe80427162842):

[image: Changes to KeyMaps.java between jline 2.11 and 2.13]

Bingo. `vi` keymap changed *to* the movement mode *from* the insert mode.

Comment: No, the keymap line has been in my .inputrc file for at least four years.  And if I change my sbt version to 0.13.9 in build.properties then it works okay with or without the keymap line.  It's only since 0.13.10 that it defaults to command mode when that keymap line is in there.  But I think sbt uses jline, not readline, so maybe that's where the change occurred.

Comment: @ecto this answer deserves a bounty

Comment: Okay, thanks Alexander.  Actually I thought your answer deserved the bounty, since it led me to find the solution, but since it was a comment and not an answer I couldn't.  This answer came in after I had already fixed the problem and it tacked on some more info but didn't really help with anything.  But I'll take your suggestion, and thanks again.